# How to replace a word only in a <p>-tag?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

How can I replace a word only in a `<p>`-Tag, and not in a `<h3>` or `<p class="no-change">`-Tag in the content?

I want to change this:

```
    <p>My Text and an Old Word and more </p>
```

in

```
    <p>My Text and an New Word and more </p>
```

I tried this:

```
    function changer($content){

    $word = str_replace('Old Word', 'New Word', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/<h3>(.*?)<\/h3>/im', $word, $content);  

    return $content; 

    }

    add_filter('the_content','changer');
```

But I get a double result...

Comment: The $content is the content from a post. ´<p>Old Word and more</p>´

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a double result because:

```
$word    = str_replace( 'Old Word', 'New Word', $content );
```

The `$word` is the full `$content` with `Old Word` replaced with `New Word`. You then replace with `$word` in the `preg_replace` so the found bit is replaced with the full `$content` less the `Old Word` which was already replaced.

Per update one approach:

```
$html = '<p>My Text and an Old Word and more </p>
<p>My Text and an Old2 Word and more </p>
<p>My Text and an Old3 Word and more </p>
<h3>My Text and an Old Word and more </h3>';
$html = preg_replace_callback('~<p>(.*?)</p>~', function ($p_content) {
    return str_replace('Old Word', 'New Word', $p_content[1]);
}, $html);
echo $html;
```

You also could use a parser and iterate over all `p` elements to see if they contain `Old Word`.

Demo: https://eval.in/582129

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for this solution! That works great! (I up vote your answer when I have 15 reputations.)